# Store a 64 bits integer in a Jet engine (Access) database?

Tags: c#, database, jet

How would it be the best / most effective / less memory consuming way to store a 64 bits integer into a Jet Engine database? I'm pretty sure their integers are 32 bits.

Comment: If it's not an option, then it means you didn't fully investigate the requirements before committing to the database engine you were going to use. That's bad planning.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton it's also completely possible that he joined a project on an MSAccess foundation that didn't require 64-bit ints when conceived. Perhaps he should tell his boss "there is no solution to this problem unless we change engines?" We're here to solve problems, even when they're not convenient.

Comment: In my opinion, there is no good solution without switching databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The largest integer MSAccess supports is a `NUMBER` (FieldSize= `LONG INTEGER`)  type
but this is not 64 bits.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714540(v=vs.85).aspx

To store numbers as large as 64 bits you will need to use the `DOUBLE` or `DECIMAL` type, but will not have "integer precision" with `DOUBLE` and you have overhead with `DECIMAL`

Alternatively you could use a `CURRENCY` type and disregard decimals. 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp

For more details on the nuances of all data types you can look here:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/introduction-to-data-types-and-field-properties-HA010233292.aspx

**EDIT:** Though you will have a limited number of significant digits in `DOUBLE` as pointed out by @ho1 in the comments below.
You can make `CURRENCY` work by inferring the digits in code if you are pressed for disk storage space but your best bet is probably `DECIMAL`

Comment: Sorry I'm a pain but, how do you create a table like that? I tried "CREATE TABLE Table3 (Stuff LONG INTEGER)" and "CREATE TABLE Table3 (Stuff NUMBER (FieldSize= LONG INTEGER) )" but didn't work.

Comment: I also tried "CREATE TABLE Table1 (Stuff LONG)" but this won't store 281474976710655 (got an Overflow error), which is less than 64 bits.

Comment: @jsoldi sorry I misunderstood. That column isn't actually 64 bits... adjusted answer!

Comment: I think `Decimal` is the only one that's correct out of the ones you suggest. `Currency` can only have 15 digits to the left of the decimal point and `Double` can only have 15 significant digits, and you'll need up to 19 digits for a 64 bit integer I believe.

Comment: @ho1 you are correct. `DOUBLE` will limit his significant digits. As for `CURRENCY` he can infer ints from the decimals by multiplying in code if he's pressed for space on disk.

Comment: @Matt: Yes, but if he does that CURRENCY trick he'd have to be extremely limited with disk space or he'd run a high risk that whoever takes over the maintenance of that code from him will submit it to the [DailyWtf](http://thedailywtf.com/) :)

Comment: @ho1 depends on his uses. MS Access has a rather restrictive size limit on database files.